# Write a binary file containing zeros to a Linux file system

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I have a large block of memory in my C program that contains zeros in the middle. I want to save this to disk without converting the values to ASCII. Will writing zeros to a file stream cause a false-negative EOF when I try to read from that file later?

Example:

```
int x[1024] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3};
// write x to disk in myfile.bin
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not if you use `fwrite` to write the memory block to a binary file. Next, `0` is not an EOF indicator. Except in some old text file formats (which used `0x1A`), there is no EOF indicator present as part of the file.

Comment: Bytes are bytes. A file is a sequence of bytes. Linux doesn't care.

Comment: If the zero sequences are very long (thousands of consecutive zeros), you could save disk space by not writing them. (I mean, use e.g `fwrite()` to write the data up to the start of the (next) sequence of zeros, then use `fseek(handle, N*sizeof (int), SEEK_CUR)` to "write" `N` zeros, assuming this is a new file, not overwriting old file data). When read, the unwritten data will read as zeros, exactly as if you had written the zeros. Such files are called "sparse", and are relatively common in Linux, Unix, and POSIXy systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null bytes in a file don't trigger EOF, even on text files.  Hitting EOF is something the I/O libraries are able to detect regardless of content.

As long as you use `write` or `fwrite` to write the memory block to disk and later use `read` or `fread` to read it, you should be fine.